# Cant open Website after adding Security functionality

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

im using the latest version of Vaadin.
I upgraded my 3 Months old project to the latest version.

Also implemented the default login system by the vaadin start generator.

But know when the Fontend gets buid following error accurs:

```
Vaadin is running in DEVELOPMENT mode - do not use for production deployments.
2023-01-05 19:40:37.742  INFO 51916 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-01-05 19:40:37.759  INFO 51916 --- [  restartedMain] de.admin.commgr.Application              : Started Application in 5.716 seconds (JVM running for 6.395)
2023-01-05 19:40:47.100  INFO 51916 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-05 19:40:47.100  INFO 51916 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-05 19:40:47.102  INFO 51916 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-01-05 19:40:47.168  INFO 51916 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator  : The number of beans implementing 'I18NProvider' is 0. Cannot use Spring beans for I18N, falling back to the default behavior
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
2023-01-05 19:42:40.395  INFO 51916 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.f.s.frontend.TaskUpdatePackages      : Frontend dependencies resolved successfully.
2023-01-05 19:42:42.484  INFO 51916 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.f.s.frontend.TaskCopyFrontendFiles   : Copying frontend resources from jar files ...
2023-01-05 19:42:42.512  INFO 51916 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.f.s.frontend.TaskCopyFrontendFiles   : Visited 23 resources. Took 27 ms.
2023-01-05 19:42:42.544  INFO 51916 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.f.server.frontend.TaskUpdateImports  : 
 
  Failed to find the following imports in the `node_modules` tree:
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/comboBoxConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/contextMenuTargetConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/messageListConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/ironListStyles.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/notificationConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/selectConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/lit-renderer.ts
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/lumo-includes.ts
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/vaadin-big-decimal-field.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/contextMenuConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/dndConnector-es6.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/menubarConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/vaadin-grid-flow-selection-column.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/virtualListConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/cookieConsentConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/datepickerConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/vaadin-map/mapConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/ironListConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/vaadin-time-picker/timepickerConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/loginOverlayConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/dialogConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/gridProConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/gridConnector.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/flow-component-renderer.js
      - @vaadin/flow-frontend/confirmDialogConnector.js
  If the build fails, check that npm packages are installed.
 
  To fix the build remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` directory to reset modules.
  In addition you may run `npm install` to fix `node_modules` tree structure.
 
 
2023-01-05 19:42:42.546  INFO 51916 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Starting Vite
 
------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
2023-01-05 19:42:44.816  INFO 51916 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Running Vite to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2023-01-05 19:42:46.071  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : Searching themes folder '/Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/frontend/themes' for theme 'testmanager'
2023-01-05 19:42:46.072  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : no assets to handle no static assets were copied
2023-01-05 19:42:46.075  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : Found theme files from '/Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/frontend/themes'
2023-01-05 19:42:46.718  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-01-05 19:42:46.719  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   VITE v3.1.0  ready in 1832 ms
 
----------------- Frontend compiled successfully. -----------------
 
2023-01-05 19:42:46.719  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-01-05 19:42:46.719  INFO 51916 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Started Vite. Time: 4173ms
2023-01-05 19:42:46.719  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:50554/VAADIN/
2023-01-05 19:42:48.056  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-01-05 19:42:48.057  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :  ERROR(TypeScript)  Cannot find module '@vaadin/flow-frontend/Flow' or its corresponding type declarations.
2023-01-05 19:42:48.057  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :  FILE  /Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/frontend/generated/index.ts:17:22
2023-01-05 19:42:48.057  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-01-05 19:42:48.058  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     15 |
2023-01-05 19:42:48.058  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     16 | // import Flow module to enable navigation to Vaadin server-side views
2023-01-05 19:42:48.058  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   > 17 | import { Flow } from '@vaadin/flow-frontend/Flow';
2023-01-05 19:42:48.058  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :        |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-01-05 19:42:48.058  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     18 |
2023-01-05 19:42:48.058  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     19 | const { serverSideRoutes } = new Flow({
2023-01-05 19:42:48.058  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :     20 |   imports: () => import('../../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports')
2023-01-05 19:42:48.059  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : 
2023-01-05 19:42:48.059  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [TypeScript] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
2023-01-05 19:42:51.098  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@vaadin/flow-frontend/vaadin-dev-tools.js" from "frontend/generated/vaadin.ts". Does the file exist?
2023-01-05 19:42:51.098  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   Plugin: vite:import-analysis
2023-01-05 19:42:51.098  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   File: /Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/frontend/generated/vaadin.ts
2023-01-05 19:42:51.098  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   1  |  import "./vaadin-featureflags.ts";
2023-01-05 19:42:51.098  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   2  |  import "./index";
2023-01-05 19:42:51.098  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   3  |  import "@vaadin/flow-frontend/vaadin-dev-tools.js";
2023-01-05 19:42:51.099  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :      |          ^
2023-01-05 19:42:51.099  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   4  |  import { applyTheme } from "./theme";
2023-01-05 19:42:51.099  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :   5  |  applyTheme(document);
2023-01-05 19:42:51.099  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :       at formatError (file:///Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-665b0112.js:40782:46)
2023-01-05 19:42:51.099  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :       at TransformContext.error (file:///Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-665b0112.js:40778:19)
2023-01-05 19:42:51.099  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :       at normalizeUrl (file:///Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-665b0112.js:37514:33)
2023-01-05 19:42:51.099  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :       at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2023-01-05 19:42:51.099  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :       at async TransformContext.transform (file:///Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-665b0112.js:37648:47)
2023-01-05 19:42:51.100  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :       at async Object.transform (file:///Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-665b0112.js:41031:30)
2023-01-05 19:42:51.100  INFO 51916 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :       at async loadAndTransform (file:///Users/admin/Documents/Development/Projects/test-manager/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-665b0112.js:37292:29)
```

These are my POM Versions:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <vaadin.version>23.3.2</vaadin.version>
    <selenium.version>4.5.3</selenium.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</parent>
```

I already tried using no vpn, disabling pihole for downloading the npm modules, frontend cleanup and so on and so on.

Comment: Have you ran a regular and a _deep_ clean via your build tool (it's usually something like `vaadinClean`) and have you checked, that all versions are properly updated in your deps?

Comment: I tried the cleanup now im getting this errors: pastebin.com/xHyjVeJt

Comment: If you make progress, please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you upgrading from a previous Vaadin 23 version?
Try running this Maven goal and then run your project again: `mvn clean vaadin:clean-frontend`

Comment: I tried the cleanup now im getting this errors:
https://pastebin.com/xHyjVeJt

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy? It seems Node isn't able to download any packages.

Comment: I was connected via my vpn to my server (for database access) I tried npm install again without this vpn and pihole disabled. Didnt work

Comment: So thats weird: I disabled vpn, pihole. Deleted node_modules and run npm install again. Everything was there whats missing but after running it was gone. And in the flow-frontend folder in the package.json is under license "UNLICENSED"

Comment: So even more weird: Now it works except when i open the website the page is white and the blue vaadin progress bar on the top loads and stops right before the end and blinks. No errors in the log or anything except from the Spring boot devtools: "NotSupportedError: Cannot define multiple custom elements with the same tag name"

Comment: Are you using Polymer Templates or your project?
If possible, share the stacktrace so we can see the whole picture.